# Gmail account storage full

Tags: gmail

I am having a Gmail account and this account is configured with window service.This window service read mails with attachments from inbox and send update back to user after particular interval.

**Problem :**

Now account space is almost full i want to take backup of all these files on another on-line storage. I am not able to upgrade my account.

Comment: Can you just delete old emails that you do not need? That would save a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Use outlook or thunderbird or zimbra email clients for desktop , Set up your gmail configurations

To setup gmail in desktop email client http://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en&ref_topic=3026306

Download all the mails , you can saveas all the mails as .eml.. and delete all the mails in server , Take the backup of these eml files in your personal cloud , You can use any email client to view that eml files

or you need any automated setup use backupify
https://www.backupify.com/products/google-apps-backup