# Gmail id over capacity

Tags: gmail

I have a Gmail business account and have several email Id's available. My current Email Id space keeps on getting full and I wish to make a new Id but as all of my contacts have my earlier Id, is there a way by which i can rename the current account and generate a fresh account to a with the old Id. OR even if i can save all the emails somewhere and not have to keep them on my id?

Comment: You can buy more storage?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra: You don't seem to be able to buy more storage for Gmail, you have a max of 25GB/user it seems. The extra storage options apply to Google Drive, not Gmail.

Comment: There are several related questions already asked here. Have you looked at [Running Out of Space on GMail, Now What?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/22669) or [gmail account is full and can not free space by deleting emails](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/40660) or [Gmail account storage full](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/42939) ? (I mean, look in the [tag:gmail] tag.)

Answer (score 1):

There are two way to resolve this:

1. Download all the emails in the original email account and transfer to another account that you would have to create. Delete everything inside the original email account and start again.
2. Create another email account, set up email forwarding from your original email to the new address. You can also opt to set the "From:" header to the old email address in the new account in the settings.